# Copy Row with Formula to Main Sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook where we do our quotation costing. There is a main sheet named "Costing Sheet" and individual sheets which can have different names. All the sheets have same format with First Row as Header. I just want a macro which will search for a values in Column A in "Costing Sheet" and compare with the values in column A of other sheets and if found copy then entire row A: W from individual sheets with formulas and format to "Costing Sheet" against the matching value. I have created a macro which copies all data and create a new sheet. but that doesn't give me desired output. I have searched several forums but couldnt find the same. It would be great help if you could assist meThis is the code I used for creating a new sheet

```
Sub CopyFromWorksheets()
Dim wrk As Workbook 
Dim sht As Worksheet 
Dim trg As Worksheet 
Dim rng As Range 
Dim colCount As Integer 
Set wrk = ActiveWorkbook 

For Each sht In wrk.Worksheets
    If sht.Name = "Master" Then
        MsgBox "There is a worksheet called as 'Master'." & vbCrLf & _
        "Please remove or rename this worksheet since 'Master' would be" & _
        "the name of the result worksheet of this process.", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next sht


Application.ScreenUpdating = False


Set trg = wrk.Worksheets.Add(After:=wrk.Worksheets(wrk.Worksheets.Count))
 'Rename the new worksheet
trg.Name = "Master"
 'Get column headers from the first worksheet
 'Column count first
Set sht = wrk.Worksheets(1)
colCount = sht.Cells(1, 255).End(xlToLeft).Column
 'Now retrieve headers, no copy&paste needed
With trg.Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, colCount)
    .Value = sht.Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, colCount).Value
     'Set font as bold
    .Font.Bold = True
End With

 'We can start loop
For Each sht In wrk.Worksheets
     'If worksheet in loop is the last one, stop execution (it is Master worksheet)
    If sht.Index = wrk.Worksheets.Count Then
        Exit For
    End If
     'Data range in worksheet - starts from second row as first rows are the header rows in all worksheets
    Set rng = sht.Range(sht.Cells(2, 1), sht.Cells(65536, 1).End(xlUp).Resize(, colCount))
     'Put data into the Master worksheet
    trg.Cells(65536, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count).Value = rng.Formula
Next sht
 'Fit the columns in Master worksheet
trg.Columns.AutoFit
 Sheets("Master").Select
colCount = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Range("L2:L" & colCount).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
 'Screen updating should be activated
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Sheets("Costing Sheet").Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The objective of your code appears to be to create a copy of the contents of all other worksheets in worksheet "Master".  If that is what you seek then this code meets your requirement.  I do not understand the code to delete any row with an empty column L and have simply commented it out.

```
Option Explicit
Sub CopyFromWorksheets()

  Dim sht As Worksheet
  Dim trg As Worksheet
  Dim rng As Range
  ' ## Long matches the natural size of an integer on a 32-bit computer.
  ' ## A 16-bit Integer variable is, I am told, slightly slower in execution.
  Dim colCount As Long
  Dim rowCount As Long    ' ## Added by me.  See later.
  Dim rowTrgNext As Long  ' ## Added by me.  See later.

  ' ## The active workbook is the default workbook.  You can have several
  ' ## workbooks open and move data between them.  If you were doing this
  ' ## then identifying the required workbook would be necessary.  In your
  ' ## situation wrk has no value.  You could argue it does no harm but I
  ' ## dislike extra, unnecessary characters because I believe they make the
  ' ## code harder to understand.  I have remove all references to wrk.

  For Each sht In Worksheets
    If sht.Name = "Master" Then
      MsgBox "There is a worksheet called as 'Master'." & vbCrLf & _
             "Please remove or rename this worksheet since 'Master' would be " & _
             "the name of the result worksheet of this process.", _
             vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "Error"
             Exit Sub
    End If
  Next sht

  'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Set trg = Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
  'Rename the new worksheet
  trg.Name = "Master"
  'Get column headers from the first worksheet
  'Column count first
  Set sht = Worksheets(1)
  ' ## 255 is the maximum number of columns for Excel 2003.
  ' ## Columns.Count gives the maximum number of columns for any version.
  colCount = sht.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
  'Now retrieve headers, no copy&paste needed
  ' ## Excel VBA provides alternative ways of achieving the same result.
  ' ## No doubt this is an accident of history but it is considered poor
  ' ## language design.  I avoid Resize and Offset (which you use later)
  ' ## because I find the resultant statements difficult to get right in
  ' ## the first place and difficult to understand when I need to update
  ' ## the code six or twelve months later.  I find .Range("Xn:Ym") or
  ' ## .Range(.Cells(n, "X"),.Cells(m, "Y")) easier to get right and
  ' ## easier to understand.  I am not asking you to agree with me; I am
  ' ## asking to consider what you would find easiest to get right and
  ' ## easiest to understand when you look at this code in six months.
  ' ## I have changed your code to show you the approach I prefer.
  Set rng = sht.Range(sht.Cells(1, 1), sht.Cells(1, colCount))
  With trg
    With .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, colCount))
      .Value = rng.Value
      'Set font as bold
      .Font.Bold = True
    End With
  End With
  rowTrgNext = 2    ' ## See later

  'We can start loop
  For Each sht In Worksheets
    'If worksheet in loop is the last one, stop execution
    ' (it is Master worksheet)
    ' ## I would favour
    ' ##    If sht.Name = "Master" Then
    ' ## because  think it is clearer.
    If sht.Index = Worksheets.Count Then
      Exit For
    End If
    ' ## 1) 65536 is the maximum number of rows for Excel 2003.
    ' ##    Rows.Count gives the maximum number of rows for any version.
    ' ## 2) As explained earlier, I do not like Resize or Offset.
    ' ## 3) I avoid doing more than one thing per statement if it means
    ' ##    I have to think hard about what is being achieved.
    ' ## 4) Rather than use End(xlUp) to determine the last unused row in
    ' ##    worksheet Master, I maintain the value in rowTgtNext.
    'Data range in worksheet - starts from second row as first rows are the header rows in all worksheets
    With sht
      ' ## Are you sure column A is full on every sheet
      ' ## This returns the last row used regardless of column
      rowCount = .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
      Set rng = sht.Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(rowCount, colCount))
    End With
    'Put data into the Master worksheet
    ' ## This copies everything: formulae, formats, etc.
    rng.Copy Destination:=trg.Range("A" & rowTrgNext)
    rowTrgNext = rowTrgNext + rowCount - 1
  Next sht
  'Fit the columns in Master worksheet
  trg.Columns.AutoFit

  ' ## I do not know what this is trying to achieve.
  ' ## It will delete any row that does not have a value in column L
  ' ## providing at least one cell in column L does contain a value.
  'Sheets("Master").Select
  'colCount = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  'Range("L2:L" & colCount).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
  'Screen updating should be activated

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Sheets("Costing Sheet").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello Mr.Tony Dallimore Thanks for your reply. Each individual sheets have a total calculation for that sheet at the bottom. When I run this macro all the data would be transferred to master sheet. But I don't need those individual sheets total in the master sheet summary. So for that I just wanted to avoid those individual sheet totals of copied to Master Sheet based on criteria of blank L columns. But there are practical issues in it. **I would only need macro which would copy whole row from individual sheets to Main Sheet based on a values in Column A of Main sheet**

Comment: For my answer, I attempted to improve your code but I did not added anything.  There is nothing in your original code that checks values against worksheet "Costing Sheet" so it is not in my version.  I have read your question more carefully and the code you seek is more than a corrected version.  What values do you search for in "Costing Sheet"?  What values do you compare them against in other sheets?  What rows do copy to "Master"?

Comment: I shall point out the basics which might be easier to understand

Comment: 1. Costing Sheet is the main sheet and we follow a template. It’s the total summary of all supplier products.
Column A is a unique numeric code for product. Column B is supplier’s name. Column C description of item. Column D Units, column E Unit Cost and rest columns are formula based calculation.
I would enter the details in Column A, B, C, D and E of Costing sheet.
2. Then I used to make a copy of the costing sheet and rename it according to supplier wise as given Column B. Thus making individual sheets for each supplier and deleting the rest of them.

Comment: 3. Then the calculations are made in each individual supplier sheet according to their currency, freight etc. that’s why individual sheets for each supplier is being made as it varies from supplier to supplier
4.Later I just want to copy and paste rows into Costing sheet from individual supplier sheets based on the Column A along with formulas used in individual sheets

Comment: I cannot match the code in your question to any of the four points above although step 4 is the most similar.  Are you trying to copy rows back to the Costing Sheet overwriting the original rows?  You could rewrite your question to give a full explanation of what you seek.  Alternatively, I have an email address "TonyDallimore23 at gmail.com" which I keep just for Stack Overflow.  You can email me files (no confidential data please) and/or explanations.

Comment: Dear **Mr. @Tony Dallimore** I have send you a mail with sample sheet and details. Expecting your kind review over it